Windows Forms Y positions aren't correct
I'm trying to use System.Drawing to draw rectangles, but when I do, the X positions of the rectangles are correct, but the Y position's aren't. I had it draw a rectangle that followed the mouse cursor to confirm this--the X position aligns with the mouse, but the Y position seems to be scaled by some percentage. I don't know what setting this is or how to correct this, and can't seem to find any information online about this.
The code gets the mouse position coordinates from MouseMove.
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseX = e.X;
    mouseY = e.Y;
}

Then draws a 10x10 rectangle at those coordinates.
G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10));

I also have it displaying the mouse coordinates in the top left. As you can see, the rectangle becomes more and more misaligned as I move the cursor down.



Changing the Autoscale property didn't fix it.

Maybe this would be helpful. Capturing cursor position with respect to a form, not to screen or vice versa, or using Cursor.Position instead of MouseEventArgs.Location.

Well, boy do I feel stupid.
I figured out the problem. After examining another program that didn't have this problem, I realized I had mistakenly put
BBG.DrawImage(BB, 0, 0, ResWidth, ResWidth);

Instead of
BBG.DrawImage(BB, 0, 0, ResWidth, ResHeight);

